# Understanding Google Play Store Statistics, Users Lost

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I was checking the statistics for my app on Google play store dashboard, and I noticed an increase in user loss after every release rollout. The numbers are alerting (Thousands), though the active installs number remains almost the same.

Does this means that users are uninstalling or could it be the number of people updating the app hence uninstalling and then reinstalling? since the peak in users lost is always after launching an update [statistics-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hlMD.png)

Comment: Any answer on that point? experiencing the same

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here, but it's compensated by installs.
My understanding is that one update = uninstall and install.
It's not great for stats indeed, but you need to look at both installs and uninstalls at once.

[image]